# Excel VBA - Date until last row

Tags: excel, vba, date, autofill

I am currently trying to achieve the following:

Column A has data in it (for example, Orange,Apple,Mango) and Column B is empty. I want to implement a box where upon entering a date it will autofill in a range.

Here's my code so far:

```
Public Sub DATERES()
Dim strUserResponse As String

strUserResponse = InputBox("Enter Date")

ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B100").Value = strUserResponse

End Sub
```

So far so good, however, my problem is that the data in A one can vary from 1 to 500-600 at times. As such, I want to modify it so that it first checks column A, and only enters the date in column B until the last row, instead of giving it a much bigger range (like B1:B1000).

Any help and advice is appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub DATERES()
Dim strUserResponse As String
dim lastrow as long

strUserResponse = InputBox("Enter Date")

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlup).row 'the 1 will get the last row for column A. Change if needed


ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B"& lastrow).Value = strUserResponse

End Sub
```

---

It's safer to use referenced `Sheets` and `Range`s instead of `ActiveSheet`.

```
' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' the 1 will get the last row for column A. Change if needed

    .Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Value = strUserResponse
End With
```

Comment: your lastrow is looking at column B, which is empty (read post), you need to fill it with dates (in Column A). so you need to search for last row in Column A.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response!! :) Works great!

Comment: @Moacir just to make sure you are not messing references in the middle of the code, I would have used `With ActiveSheet` before the lastrow. or better yet to use a referenced object `With Sheets("yoursheetname")` ..

Comment: You mean like `lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlup).row`? or maybe 
`With ActiveSheet
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlup).row 


Range("B1:B"& lastrow).Value = strUserResponse
End With`

Comment: @llorcs read my Tip in my answer below, it will help you save time with users entering bad data in `InputBox`

Answer (score 1):

FYI, if you want your `ImputBox` to force the user to enter a value in a `Date` format, use the lines below:

```
Dim strUserResponse As Date

strUserResponse = Application.InputBox("Enter Date", , FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)
```